# Unknown plant, please help me identify it

Tags: species-identification, botany

Years ago I was into keeping tropical fruit trees/bushes indoors. One of them didn't do well under my care so I planted it outside to enjoy the final year before European winter gets it. It somehow survived, barely. Each year it did better though so 5-6 years later it's full of edible fruit. I don't know what it is. Can somebody identify it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is it this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTYMG7mziRw ?

Comment: The fruit looks a lot like something from the *Syzygium* genus. Can you show us a cross section (lengthwise) of the fruit?

Comment: @JimN I think you may be correct.

Comment: crush one fruit, see if it has flesh crunchy like apple - if so probably Syzygium

Comment: It worries me a bit that you don’t know the species, yet you know the fruits are edible. I hope you simply remember it’s supposed to be edible when you first got the plant?

Comment: JimN, yes that was it. Jujube (Chinese Date). Some variant of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a cultivar of Jujube (Ziziphus zizyphus) also known as Chinese date - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jujube

This is based on JimN's correct observation. I looked at a few dozen images of Ziziphus Zizyphus - both fruit and leaves. They appear to be identical. The fruit tastes as described. The fruiting progression matches the description in Wikipedia.

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but what you are suggesting is an online form of politics and bureaucracy (time-wasting). I will edit my answer to oblige